# Is it possible to install Gimp on Ubuntu Server and use it in command line from a php script?

Tags: command-line, server, php, gimp

I have a project where the users will be able to upload images from their browser. The project is coded with PHP. We need to process the uploaded images with some advanced filters and we need a good result.

I googled around and found out that I can use gimp in command line. (http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/)

I know that I can use PHP exec() to execute external applications. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

So my questions are:
Can I install Gimp on Ubuntu Server with no GUI?
Is is possible/a good idea to use Gimp to process image from php instead of using GD?

Thank you all! I'm still a noob with Ubuntu Server and Web server stuff.

Comment: GIMP has a dependency on using graphical libraries and runtimes, the last I checked.  I'm not certain you can use GIMP for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side, imagemagick is a better option s it does not use X (graphical interface). It does a nice job and has several options.

There are many online tutorials, see :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561895/resize-a-list-of-images-in-line-command

http://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/09/09/resizing-bash-script-batch-resizing-using-command-line/